# Javascript method of getting day of week from string?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, datetime

Say I have a string like the following:
`2013-11-22T08:50:33+0000`
Which is `Friday, November 2013, 8:50:33.`

How would I go about telling that it's Friday given the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `date.getDay()` to get the day as a number, and then you'll use a map, array or anything else you'd like to match that number to a day

```
var day = new Date("2013-11-22T08:50:33+0000").getDay(); // returns 5
```

so you can do something like:

```
var s = "2013-11-22T08:50:33+0000" 

var days = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
]

var d = days[new Date(s).getDay()]; // Friday
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/67mZB/)

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept your comment as an answer when it lets me.